# Why are greenDao Queries taking 15 seconds?

Tags: android, greendao

So we are using GreenDao as our ORM and Just yesterday I noticed some severe lag in a new feature.  After some investigating I found it wasn't our code but rather some Code generated by greenDao.

When we call `someEntity.getContacts()`  It takes between 10 to 15 seconds to run the query.  A week ago that same code was very fast.  Does any one know why it is taking so long and what we can do to fix it?  I've included code bellow.

Code to build Models (DaoGenerator.java) This is the code we actually wrote.

```
/*
 * MyEntity Entity
 */
Entity lead = schema.addEntity("MyEntity");
myEntity.setSuperclass("MainSyncableEntity");
myEntity.implementsInterface("ClusterItem");
myEntity.implementsInterface("PointQuadTree.Item");
myEntity.implementsInterface("BaseEntityGetter");
myEntity.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
myEntity.setConstructors(false);

// Attributes
myEntity.addStringProperty("myEntityId").unique().index();
myEntity.addStringProperty("clientUniqueId").unique();
myEntity.addDateProperty("dateModified").notNull().index();
myEntity.addDateProperty("visibleCreated").notNull().index();
myEntity.addDateProperty("visibleModified").notNull().index();
myEntity.addStringProperty("notes").notNull();
myEntity.addStringProperty("businessName").notNull();
myEntity.addStringProperty("statusId").notNull();
myEntity.addStringProperty("ownerId").notNull();
/*
 * Contact Entity
 */
Entity contact = schema.addEntity("Contact");
contact.setSuperclass("MainSyncableEntity");
contact.implementsInterface("BaseEntityGetter");
contact.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
contact.setConstructors(false);

// Attributes
contact.addStringProperty("contactId").unique().index();
contact.addStringProperty("clientUniqueId").unique();
contact.addDateProperty("dateModified").notNull().index();
contact.addStringProperty("firstName").notNull();
contact.addStringProperty("lastName").notNull();
contact.addStringProperty("email").notNull();
contact.addStringProperty("phonePrimary").notNull();
contact.addStringProperty("phoneSecondary").notNull();
contact.addStringProperty("ssn").notNull();
contact.addStringProperty("dateOfBirth");
Property leadContactSortOrder = contact.addIntProperty("sortOrder").notNull().getProperty();

/*
* MyEntity Relationships
*/
myEntity.addToMany(contact, contactMyEntityId, "contacts").orderAsc(contactSortOrder);


  /*
 * Contact Relationships
 */
// Properties
Property contactLeadId = contact.addLongProperty("contactMyEntityId").notNull().index().getProperty();

// Relationships
contact.addToOne(myEntity, contactMyEntityId);
```

The Generated method that runs slow:

```
public List<LeadContact> getContacts() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (contacts == null) {
        if (daoSession == null) {
            throw new DaoException("Entity is detached from DAO context");
        }
        LeadContactDao targetDao = daoSession.getLeadContactDao();
        List<LeadContact> contactsNew = targetDao._queryLead_Contacts(id);
        synchronized (this) {
            if (contacts == null) {
                contacts = contactsNew;
            }
        }
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

And the Generated Code to do the query:

```
/** Internal query to resolve the "contacts" to-many relationship of Lead. */
public List<LeadContact> _queryLead_Contacts(long leadContactLeadId) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (lead_ContactsQuery == null) {
            QueryBuilder<LeadContact> queryBuilder = queryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.where(Properties.LeadContactLeadId.eq(null));
            queryBuilder.orderRaw("T.'SORT_ORDER' ASC");
            lead_ContactsQuery = queryBuilder.build();
        }
    }
    Query<LeadContact> query = lead_ContactsQuery.forCurrentThread();
    query.setParameter(0, leadContactLeadId);
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: Is the lead contact id in the db indexed?

Comment: The other thing I'd question is if you're simultaneously runnign querries ont he sameobject elsewhere.  There's a synchronized block there, so only one query will run at a time.

Comment: @GabeSechan  I believe it is indexed  We call .index() on the property in the DaoGenerator.    Do you know how I can check the actual table to see if it is indexed.      I'll look into the synchronized block.

Comment: @GabeSechan  It was the synchronization block.  There is another bit of code that is writing to the database frequently in a transaction and that is what is causing the delays in queries.